# Trouble with array of dictionaries, ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following error.

```
game.rb:46:in `play': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from game.rb:45:in `each'
from game.rb:45:in `play'
from game.rb:56
```

with this code,

```
def play()
            currentTile = nil
            @tiles.each do |tile|
                    if(tile['Name'] == 'Starting Square')
                            currentTile = tile
                    end

                    puts("#{currentTile['Desciption']}")
            end
end
```

This is part of a text adventure game, I am playing with @tiles is an array of tiles that was read from a file. Each tile is a dictionary.

Thanks for any help, I cant figure this out

Comment: Note that in Ruby, what Python calls dictionaries are here called hashes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def play()
  currentTile = nil
  @tiles.each do |tile|
    currentTile = tile if tile['Name'] == 'Starting Square'
    puts("#{currentTile['Desciption']}") unless currentTile.nil?
  end
end
```

You've got an error because currentTile became a tile not in the very first iteration. It get 'description' key only when name of tile is 'Starting Square'

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're probably trying to debug by printing whether or not `currentTile` is set yet. All fine and dandy.

However, note that, until the name matches `Starting Square`, `currentTile` will continue to be `nil`, and you can't access the property of a `nil` object. Maybe the starting square isn't the first tile on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to print the description of currentTile after you've located it, but you have the puts inside the search loop.

Try:

```
def play()
            currentTile = nil
            @tiles.each do |tile|
                    if(tile['Name'] == 'Starting Square')
                            currentTile = tile
                    end

            end
            puts("#{currentTile['Desciption']}")
end
```

There's still no guarantee that you won't get a nil reference (if there are no tiles with the name 'Starting Square', but the code you've got will only work if the very first tile in @tiles is the one titled 'Starting Square'

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to have you covered (indexing currentTile after it is set to nil), but for whatever its worth, you might want to be using symbols for your keys and values, rather than strings.  Symbols are faster to look up and faster to compare, as they're just named pointers, whereas checking string equality is an O(n) operation.

So something like

```
def play()
        currentTile = nil
        @tiles.each do |tile|
                if(tile[:name] == :startingSquare)
                        currentTile = tile
                end

        end
        puts("#{currentTile['Desciption']}") unless currentTile.nil?
end
```

Then again, I don't know your application, maybe it's perfectly appropriate ^_^